# Singular $3$-fold with $b_{2}=1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a complex, rational, $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein $3$-fold with at most terminal singularities, and $H_{2}(X,\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$. Is $X$ Fano?

By Kleiman ampleness criterion this is equivalent to $(-K_{X})^3>0$, but the standard argument from the smooth case of using Kodaira dimension doesn't quite work.

Comment: A nodal hypersurface of high degree is a variety of general type with $b_2 = 1$.

Comment: Is it rational?

Comment: Every nodal hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{4}$ of degree at least 5 is non-rational. See remark 3 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405150.pdf. I required that the variety in rational, so atleast in dimension 3 your example doesn't work. Actually dimension $3$ is my main motivation so if you don't mind I will add this assumption.

Comment: This should be fine.  Either $K_X$ is anti-ample, ample, or trivial, since Picard rank is 1.  The latter two are impossible since you're assuming terminal+rational.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it would be rather strange to have a rational variety with $-K_{X}=0$ or even $K_{X}$ is ample. But I would like to know a proof if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this just follows from exercise 4.1.9 here https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~cb496/birgeom.pdf.